# NoclassDefFoundError while using hbc jar file

Tags: java

I am trying to use hbc jar file to fetch twitter data without using mongodb and i am getting error like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twitter/joauth/UrlCodec
at com.twitter.hbc.core.endpoint.BaseEndpoint.addPostParameter(BaseEndpoint.java:90)
at com.twitter.hbc.core.endpoint.DefaultStreamingEndpoint.filterLevel(DefaultStreamingEndpoint.java:95)
at com.abhi.Main.createHoseBirdClient(Main.java:68)
at com.abhi.Main.main(Main.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.twitter.joauth.UrlCodec
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 4 more
```

Comment: please share your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download `joauth.jar` and add it to your classpath.

Comment: In joauth.jar there is no UrlCodec.class file.

Comment: @abhishek in Version 4.0.0 it should be included: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjoauth400jar.htm

Comment: You can try with the newest version: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twitter/joauth/6.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Use this Jar file from [Here](http://www.findmaven.net/detail/com.twitter/joauth/6.0.0/com.twitter.joauth.NonceValidator/1/0). It contains com.twitter.joauth.urlcodec Class.